# Does Telepathy allow Emotional Urging?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Telepathy (mind 3) allows to (core book p.212)

> **share** thoughts, images and **emotions**

Does it mean it can have the same effects as Emotional Urging (Mind 2) which (core book p.207):

> project emotions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, higher rank Arcanum effects can encompass or reproduce lower rank effects. If you want to push an emotion you're feeling — akin to a thought you're thinking or an image you're imagining — through a Telepathic link you've created, that's just fine.

However, if you wanted to use that link to make a *new* emotional urge, like making someone you're in Mind contact with afraid when you are not yourself afraid, that'd be a second effect, although one with lots of circumstantial advantages.